# Apache Ignite | TCP discovery SPI

Tags: ignite

What is TCP discovery SPI in Apache Ignite and what it does?

What **127.0.0.1:47500..47509** in example-cache.xml of apache ignite?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Ignite nodes are all the same and join together automatically to form a cluster. The "Discovery" mechanism is how they find each other, by using the IP address and port of at least 1 other Ignite node to join the rest of the cluster.

TCP Discovery uses a TCP connection to the addresses and ports specified.

`127.0.0.1:47500..47509` is a shortened notation that says contact IP `127.0.0.1` (also known as your localhost) and use ports from `47500` to `47509`.

This is used in the example code so you can easily run a few instances of Ignite for testing on your computer and they all will connect to each other as a cluster, even though they are all running on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a component responsible for nodes discovery. Please refer to this page for details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery

Comment: Valentin,Thank you for reply. But I don't understand the this line127.0.0.1:47500..47509 in example-cache.xml of apache ignite?

Specially 47500..47509

Comment: This is the range of ports node tries to connect to. It needs to connect to one of the existing nodes to join the cluster.